# Bots suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, spam

So over the last few weeks, I've had the same one of my answers edited, usually once or twice a day, but not every day it seems. Below is a screen-shot of my notifications (expanded with Firebug)

[image: Spam Bots]

I haven't looked at every single edit, but out of the 10+ I've looked at, they all look the same:

[image: Suggested Edits]

Where the random text links off to various websites.

I'm really unsure of what to do about this situation; it's really annoying, and being done by an "anonymous user" whom I can't report. I assumed it would have been reported and fixed by now, but the fact that it hasn't makes me think it's time for me to speak up about this.

Finally, just so I'm actually asking a question, how do I make this stop?

**EDIT:** [Here's a link to the most recent incident](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2782142)

Comment: Make a Meta.SO post for a mod to see. A link to one of those edits wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: You don't make it stop. Spam edits get suggested. Why they pick yours I don't know.

Comment: Can't wait to see who we'll get to bitch-slap for approving any of these edits.

Comment: One solution would be for a moderator to lock that particular post, but I'm not sure if it's the "done thing". I can imagine how annoying it is getting so many notifications.

Comment: Added the link. Thanks for the suggestion @Undo

Comment: Wait. Is that Gucci I see among the spam content? PEKKA IS THAT YOU?

Comment: It doesn't say "Genuine"...

Comment: This post on cooking also received several spam edits, one every few days, but it seems to have stopped now: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19863/are-fungal-toxins-a-significant-problem-in-coffee-and-if-so-can-they-be-avoide/19869#19869

Comment: I'm impressed. Not a single reviewer approved any of the 19 spam suggested edits on that answer. I have to say, the review audits seem to be doing their job in stopping rubber-stamp approvers.

Comment: The real problem here is how many reviewers picked *invalid edit* instead of *vandalism*.

Comment: Since these spam edits keep coming in every day on this answer, I'm trying out locking it for a week to see if that will drive them away.

Comment: I'll pay attention to it once the lock is lifted and let you know if it's still going on afterwards. Thanks @BradLarson

Comment: @BradLarson I see the lock has been lifted. There were 4 more suggested edits in a 3 hour time-span 5 hours ago. Just thought you'd find this information useful.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy - Really? Sorry about that. I'm going to pass this along to the team to see if there's something else that can be done about it.

Comment: @BradLarson It's alright. I understand how these things are. I hope something gets figured out. Good luck

Comment: @BradLarson: Alas, [review doesn't always help](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/142966).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Flag that for the Mathematics mods to look at. I'd look into the review histories of both of those reviewers and most likely hand out manual bans.

Comment: @BradLarson: Already did that, just thought I'd post it as an example here. Also just flagged [one on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3681797) that was rejected 3-1 (which is still one "approve" too many, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

We had a case like this on a site I moderate.  Every week or two a spambot (from a new IP address) would attempt a malicious edit on the same answer.  The answer had nothing to do with the products being spammed (it's not like somebody was targeting a particular question/topic).  Naturally this was frustrating for the affected user.

We learned that posts that are very short are more susceptible to spam edits.  (I'm being deliberately vague because I haven't found the details in public, only in moderator communications.)  If you can, without adding noise, lengthen that answer, that might inoculate your answer against the bot.  (That doesn't mean you'll never see spam attempts from humans, but your answer will be a less-juicy target.)  If the answer shouldn't be any longer, ask the moderators on your site to talk with a community manager; in our case we were able to take some specific actions for the one answer that was being hit frequently.