# If a suspected spam edit of my post is rejected as spam what should I do with that info? Should we remove that notification?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, spam, global-inbox

Recently I've had a couple of my posts get defaced by spam bots (I assume bots).
Your Automatic-Robotic-Spam-Edit-Labeler (ARSEL) correctly identified it, as did the reviewers; rejecting it as spam. When I logged on this morning I saw the notification of an edit. I clicked to here https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24057 and got that warm glow of seeing the system working as it should.

Recently there have been a few too many warm glows and I'm getting rather hot, so I'm wondering **(TL;DR:) Am I supposed to do anything having received notification of a rejected spam edit? If not, should notifications about possible spam edits be removed if rejected as such?**

Comment: I'm assuming I don't have to alert mods/etc. if I get many as [this person has](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194566/bots-suggesting-edits); I'm assuming the system does something like that anyway. If I should alert mods, how many edits before it's worth alerting?

Comment: The system has been improved since then after my [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210201/protected-questions-and-editing) but if you are getting many I would raise it here so that the developers can have another look

Comment: One reason this might be useful is for identifying bad reviewers. If you look at the spam suggested edit, and any of the reviewers approved it, flag and let us know. We want to know about stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that notification should simply be removed if the edit is rejected as spam. It only annoys the author of the edited post who can't do anything about the spam anyway.

The spam defense mechanisms are entirely automatic, based on feedback from flags and moderator actions. There is no need to notify anyone unless the defense mechanisms are obviously failing.

Comment: Another option is to "stack" them together same way it's showing "6 comments" with only the latest as preview, and not 6 separate items for each comment. So it will show "50 edits suggested", linking only to the latest. (the grouping is per post of course)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Those notifications have no value at all, I don't see why we should keep them even in the stacked form.

Comment: There's always a slight chance of false positive i.e. something valid that was rejected as spam.

Comment: Also if there is a lot of spam the user can notify developers so they can look to return their spam filters